# multi-schema or multi-database in H2, which is better?

Tags: database, h2

For a use case like multi-tenancy support in database, I wanted to know which of the following options fares better in terms of performance and maintainability?

1. same database, different schema (one schema per tenant)
2. different DB instance per tenant

Statistically, data size per tenant could be somewhere around 35 MB (under load) and around 25000 records in a couple of tables. Other tables (around 15 in all) will have very less amount of data comparatively and there are no BLOB/CLOB type of columns in the database.

What are their pros and cons? And are there any other better options than these?

Regards,
Aditya

Comment: Related: [*Multiple independent H2 databases within one JVM*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31150193/642706)